# What's wrong with my Garrett Robbi questions?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, deleted-questions

I didn't mean anything bad. I come to poker SE as a chess follower, so I figured I'd give more attention to the 2022 [poker cheating scandal](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/88625/would-it-be-have-been-unhelpful-for-hans-niemann-to-bring-up-magnus-carlsens) which didn't seem to get as much attention as the 2022 [chess cheating scandal](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/88985/is-evidence-of-rumours-of-a-defendants-racism-unhelpful-in-a-defamation-case-in).

What's wrong with my Garrett Adelstein Robbi Jade Lew questions?

https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/11923/robbi-and-garrett-run-it-twice

https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/11915/re-garrett-adelstein-and-robbi-jade-lew-does-running-it-twice-decrease-cheating

https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/11902/if-robbi-jade-lew-is-cheating-how

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is wrong with the questions persay. According to the timeline, they have been deleted by the Community bot as dead inactive questions. You can post them but it doesn't mean people want to answer them. To me a lot of these questions, especially when the scandal broke, were very opinion based as we needed to wait for the investigation to happen. Any answer at that time would likely be heavily opinion based or very subjective. Another potential answer to give you is that no one here was particularly interested in the topic.

For the most part the type of questions that the Poker SE mostly deal with are poker related directly, not massively revolving around controversy, scandals, or what people are doing in the poker world, etc. You mostly get questions around hand analysis, casino rules, etc.